# swap data lines and address lines in ROM contents in C

Tags: c, embedded

I am reprogramming the contents of a Rom in an old embedded system,(roland tr505 drum machine, fyi)

the system originally used a mask rom with a nonstandard pinout (Tc531000). and some data and address lines were swapped around to make pcb routing easier. I will be replacing it with a readily available 27c010 eprom
the data is 128k long and it contains 8 bit unsigned pcm audio.

because the address and data bits are connected to the chip in a non standard way, i need to write a program that re orders the rom contents.
e.g address bits a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7 become a2,a4,a3,a1,a5,a6,a7,a0
and data bits are reordered, e.g d0,d1, d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7 become d4,d3,d2,d1,d0,d5,d6,d7

I have read the 128k rom contents into an array in memory:

char input_romdata[131072];

this is how i ended up remapping data bits thanks to the nudges i got here:

```
//data lines edit these to change the data mapping
// here bits 6 and 7 are swapped.
#define D0 0
#define D1 1
#define D2 2
#define D3 3
#define D4 4
#define D5 5
#define D6 7
#define D7 6

#define SET_BIT(byte, bit) ((byte) |= (1UL << (bit)))
#define CLEAR_BIT(byte,bit) ((byte) &= ~(1UL << (bit)))
#define IS_SET(byte,bit) (((byte) & (1UL << (bit))) >> (bit))
#define TOGGLE_BIT(byte,bit) ((byte) ^= (1UL << (bit)))
#define CLEAR_BIT(byte,bit) ((byte) &= ~(1UL << (bit)))

unsigned char swap_byte(unsigned char inchar)
{ //this function swaps data pins
    unsigned char outchar = 0;
    for (int bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++){ // 1 bit at a time
        switch (bit){
            case 0: // if this is the bit that corresponds to D0 in the remapped byte..
                if (IS_SET(inchar, bit)) SET_BIT(outchar, D0); // set the corseponding bit in outchar
                break;
            case 1:
                if (IS_SET(inchar, bit)) SET_BIT(outchar, D1);
                break;
            case 2:
                if (IS_SET(inchar, bit)) SET_BIT(outchar, D2);
                break;
            case 3:
                if (IS_SET(inchar, bit)) SET_BIT(outchar, D3);
                break;
            case 4:
                if (IS_SET(inchar, bit)) SET_BIT(outchar, D4);
                break;
            case 5:
                if (IS_SET(inchar, bit)) SET_BIT(outchar, D5);
                break;
            case 6:
                if (IS_SET(inchar, bit)) SET_BIT(outchar, D6);
                break;
            case 7:
                if (IS_SET(inchar, bit)) SET_BIT(outchar, D7);
                break;


        }

    }

    return outchar;
}
```

now to try the address remapping.

Comment: The best way of learning is for you to try write the code. And note that StackOverflow isn't a code writing service. Try a paper exercise writing out what a byte would become if some bits are swapped, e.g. bit 7 and 0. Then think about if address lines 0 and 1 are swapped, what happens to the byte order.

Comment: Use something like `for (addr = 0; addr < 131072; addr++) output_romdata[addr_munge(addr)] = data_munge(input_romdata[addr]);`. You will need to write the `addr_munge` and `data_munge` functions according to your requirements. Or possibly, `for (addr = 0; addr < 131072; addr++) output_romdata[addr] = data_munge(input_romdata[addr_munge(addr)]);`, depending on which makes most sense to you.

Comment: Your swap_byte() contains two errors in the for statement: the final index should be 8, and the test should be "less than", not "greater than". Apart than that, it is pretty correct.

Comment: To me this looks all wrong... for instance the code never uses `inchar` - I guess `inchar` holds the data to be swapped

Comment: `for (int bit = 0; bit > 7; bit++)` means that you never enters the loop. Maybe you want `for (int bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++)` ?

Comment: It’s a start but likely not correct even with some suggestions above - now test it! Write a test harness that calls it with data and checks the results. And I suggest you stop looking for approval at every step or you will never get the confidence to write code by yourself. TBH it would help if people let you find out the problems in your code by yourself, by testing it and debugging it.

Comment: Please state your problem clearly. What does "swap data and address lines" mean? Do you need to reverse, rotate or swap bits inside individual bytes? Right now, your function: 1) never reads `inchar`, 2) doesn't enter the loop at all because `bit > 7` is immediately false, 3) contains an unnecessary `switch` statement which would, if the `for` statement bug was fixed, simply set all bits in `outchar`, in a rather inefficient way.

Comment: i have fixed all the simple errors in the data bit swapping function and made it work,
 i have tested it with a fimware image and checked the files in a hex editor it seems to be fine now.
 i still need to write the address mapping function.

Comment: i suppose i should iterate through the array containing the original data, and copy each byte to its correct position in a new array.

for future reference how should i better ask, "what is the best way to go about this?"  rather than "can you help me write a routine to do this?"